# Woocommerce Paypal Standard: get Sandbox status

Tags: woocommerce, paypal-sandbox

I'm working on a code to programmatically change paypal account based on cart, I've just one problem, I want to know if sandbox is active on Paypal Standard Gateway to serve sandbox account, or if I'm on live mode to serve live account. Someone knows how to get the sandbox status?

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, stupid question, I've looked for an hour but at the end I realize that the simple way is a standard wordpress get_option api:
`get_option("woocommerce_paypal_settings")`

Thanks